# не определяются java классы

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Возник вопрос, копаюсь долго не могу решить: что-то слетело в студио и java классы во всех проектах не определяются, вместо привычного значка java класса появился значок синглтона. .. Не подскажите как решить? Jdk прописан верно. clean + rebuild и invalidate cashes/restart не помогли. 
Проекты на эмулятор выводятся и работают. Но код в java классах не определяется, среда не дает подсказки, не отмечает ошибки и т.д.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B02lXSNQ8nuuRm5zY3JOTE5sOVE

Answer (score 0):

В настройках проекта(Project structure) укажите директории с исходным кодом

Comment: Во вкладке SDK Location прописаны все директории и SDK, и JDK, и NDK.